# Please advise how to set background-image correctly

Tags: html, css, spring

I am trying to set background image for div, but it works only if I provide absolute path ("http://etc..."). When I set relative path ("/img/picture.jpg") it is not displayed for some reason. I checked the file and folder name 100 times, acctually the same approach works on another html page in my app. Tried to rebuild app with maven few times. Please see the code below.

```
   ...... <body>

<div class="background-wrap">
    <div class="background" >
</div>
</div>

<form name="loginForm" id="accesspanel" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <h1 id="litheader">AVIATRADE</h1>
    <div class="inset">

        <div class="success" th:if="${success}">
            Success! Please login.
        </div>
        <p>
            <input  name="username" id="email" class="usernameInput" placeholder="Username">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="password"  name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </p>
        <div th:if="${param.error}" class="error">
            Invalid username or password
        </div>
        <input class="loginLoginValue" type="hidden" name="service" value="login" />
    </div>
    <p class="p-container">
        <input type="submit" name="Login" id="go" value="Login">
    </p>
</form>
<br>

<button class="open-button" id="open1" >Sign up</button>
..........</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #1b1b1b;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
}

.background-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
    /*background-image: url("https://beaconmaster.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/airport-wallpapers-005.jpg?189db0&189db0");*/
    background-image: url("/img/loginBackground.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 105%;
    position: relative;
    width: 105%;
    right: -2.5%;
    left: -2.5%;
    top: -2.5%;
    bottom: -2.5%;
}
```

Spring Boot folders

[image: spirng]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved the problem - Spring Security was blocking static resources so I had to add:

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**","/static/**","/img/**");
    }
```